# How can I stop an Invalid Email Address from going to next activity

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I am currently working on my Login Activity and I am having troubles with my email validation. Even though the toast message does say "Invalid Email Addresss" it still goes to the next Activity instead of staying in the LoginActivity until it was a Valid Email address.

Here is my LoginActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.wny.wecare.handler.JSONParser;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            "[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" +
                    "@" +
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" +
                    "(" +
                    "." +
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" +
                    ")+"
            );


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputEmail;
    Button btnLogin;

    public String strUid;

    // url to create new user
    private static String url_create_user = "http://infinitycodeservices.com/create_user.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private LoginButton btnFacebookLogin;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        // Edit Text
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);

        // button click event
        btnCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email=inputEmail.getText().toString();
                if(checkEmail(email))
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Valid Email Addresss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Email Addresss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // creating new user in background thread
                new CreateNewUser().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new User
     * */
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging In..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating User
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Setup ArrayList from main activity to store results
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> emailList = new ArrayList<Map<String,  String>>();

            String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString().trim();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));

            // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_create_user, params);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                try {
                    JSONObject c = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
                    //Fill map
                    Iterator iter = c.keys();
                    while(iter.hasNext())   {
                        String currentKey = (String) iter.next();
                        map.put(currentKey, c.getString(currentKey));
                    }
                    emailList.add(map);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            };

            //SAVE
            SharedPreferences ui = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edUi = ui.edit();
            edUi.putString("uid", strUid);
            edUi.putString("email", email);
            edUi.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();

            // Returns Toast "Login success!"
            //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute your aync task inside true condition

```
   if(checkEmail(email)) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Valid Email Addresss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // creating new user in background thread 
     new CreateNewUser().execute();
            }       
                else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Email Addresss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put curly braces in if condition like:-

```
        // button click event
            btnCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String email=inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    if(checkEmail(email)){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Valid Email Addresss",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      // creating new user in background thread
                      new CreateNewUser().execute();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid Email Addresss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }
            });
```

Problem with you code is that you are executing asyntask evry time.